# Can I use repeat as intransitive verb?

Tags: word-usage, grammar, verbs, transitivity, intransitive-preposition

Okay I give up! The original sentence was this from my writing:

> "Now that you have read the insights, in order to move on to the future, you would be better off if you now leave them behind. There will be most probably times you will automatically retrieve whatever you acquired from past knowledge to put into practice and make your own meaningful versions of it tailored to your unique experiences. Then you will have to repeat and again leave these behind to keep on living wherever you paused at, each time much lighter and more free and welcome to the ever growing life."

I felt that, repeat without a following "it" or "all this" does not sound fully right to me somehow. also these in "again leave these behind" might not refer to insights anymore because inbetween there is another sentence that might have cut the connection to such reference.

What do you think?

Comment: "You will have to repeat" is OK, but in my opinion "...and again cry all the tears" sounds a bit odd.

Comment: ok I tried to make it sound a little more normal :) I heard the expression "crying tears" in a song though, I think it is artistically nice way to say so dont you think?

Comment: By "again do all the wrong things", do you mean "correct (fix) all the errors"?

Comment: okay I expanded my question after your comments

Comment: What are you "repeat"ing? It isn't clear, or maybe I'm too logical to get it. Do you mean "meaningful versions of it"? If so, I think you need to use "repeat *them*".

Comment: Offhand intransitive usages seem to be commands like "Repeat after me" or "Lather, Rinse, Repeat".

Comment: repeat this whole process..

Comment: Instead of "repeat" here, I would be more direct: "Then you will have to do it all over again, and leave these behind to keep on living wherever you paused <strike>at</strike>..."

Comment: In a full sentence (*rinse and repeat* is akin to headlinese) I would use intransitive *repeat* only when the subject is a process or pattern. “This broadcast repeats in two hours.” “The tartan repeats every 84 threads.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Repeat* without an object can mean *do again*, with the action being done understood from context.  A common saying on the back of shampoo bottles is *rinse and repeat*, which means to wash your hair again (never been clear on when to stop).

Comment: never been clear on when to stop :DD