# better way to say "And over again"

Tags: idiomatic-language, idiom-request

> "He hit his head and then his body and then did the same over again."

> "He hit his head and then his body and his his head and then his body..."

How do you say this properly? I don't remember the idiomatic expression used for this.

Comment: Look up synonyms for "repeatedly" and use one that strikes your fancy. But don't strike your fancy repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only repeating it once:

> "He hit his head and then his body, and then did it again."

> "He hit his head and then his body, and then did it once more."

If you're repeating it several times:

> "He hit his head and then his body over and over again."

> "He repeatedly hit his head and body."

If you want to be a little bit funny with it, you could steal the phrase [*to rinse and repeat*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/97671/140174):

> "He hit his head and then his body, then rinsed and repeated."

It sounds a lot better when using a passive voice though:

> "Hit his head, then his body, then rinse and repeat"

However this sounds more like instructions on how to assault the subject of the sentence and might change the meaning.